# How to work with Session and Include statement in PHP?

Tags: php, session, logic

I am having many files with multple includes one into another like below,

`File1` is included in `File2` and then `File2` is under `File3`

Now I want to declare a session variable `site_user_conutry` from File1 and then I am checking on File2 that if there is any no value in the session variable then Only I am including File1.php

I have added `session_start();` in each [age but still its not working ??

Please tell me how can I make session work in the above condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you setting the session variable? You should try setting it like so:

```
$_SESSION['site_user_conutry'] = 'United-Kingdom';
```

Have you placed session_start() at the very top of the document, or at least before you output any information?

Comment: Yes, I am declaring the session as you demonstrated. and also I am adding session_start() at the top of every page.

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump($_SESSION)? Completely empty?

Answer (score 2):

Within File2

```
if ($_SESSION["site_user_country"] != null) 
{
    include_once(File3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do session_start in first lines of code just once.

Documentation says:
As from version 4.4.3, calling session_start() while the session has already been started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply *be ignored*.

If file1 is included in file2 that code from file2 is done before file1. So if you declare something in file1 may not be seen in file2 (depends on code...), anyway it is not modern way pf php programming. (see oo and __autoload)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are including files that have code execution, not functions.

The code that includes File1 and sets the session variables must be executed before the code on File2 on the first iteraction.

In the next iteractions the session will hold the values for you.

To set an session variable use the $_SESSION global array.

```
$_SESSION["name"] = "value";
```